# How to update Windows behind policies (via registry)

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-update, regedit

How to update windows behind restrictives policies (who is handled by WSUS administrator) ? Is it possible to do via registry (regedit) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it s possible to update if you are administrator of your machine.
Create and execute (**as Administator**) the file **wsus.reg** with the following code :

**Note :** The following script set the registries to allow your machine to update windows with the updates from the official Microsoft update server.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"DisableOSUpgrade"=dword:00000000
"ElevateNonAdmins"=dword:00000001
"TargetGroupEnabled"=dword:00000000
"TargetGroup"=""
"WUServer"=""
"WUStatusServer"=""


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoWindowsUpdate"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"AUOptions"=dword:00000002
"AutoInstallMinorUpdates"=dword:00000000
"DetectionFrequencyEnabled"=dword:00000001
"DetectionFrequency"=dword:00000008
"NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers"=dword:00000001
"NoAutoUpdate"=dword:00000000
"NoAUAsDefaultShutdownOption"=dword:00000000
"NoAUShutdownOption"=dword:00000000
"ScheduledInstallDay"=dword:00000007
"ScheduledInstallTime"=dword:00000014
"RebootRelaunchTimeoutEnabled"=dword:00000001
"RebootRelaunchTimeout"=dword:000000f0
"RescheduleWaitTimeEnabled"=dword:00000000
"UseWUServer"=dword:00000000
```

Then restart your machine and go to Windows Update Settings and check for updates.

Et voilà :)

Edit: You can have an explanation for each registry on the [Microsoft documentation website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd939844(v=ws.10))

Comment: What's the benefit about these registry settings?

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: I have edited my answer to add an official link and explain better what does the script file.